# What can I do when I see passengers without masks on my flight?

Tags: air-travel, covid-19

Yesterday, I was on an international flight to Germany with WiZZ airline. Prior to the flight I received several email reminders to wear a mask in connection with COVID19 epidemic situation. I certainly adhered to this regulation even though I am fully vaccinated and my kids have negative COVID tests. But many passengers aggressively refused to do so. Moreover, they completely ignore the request of flight attendants to wear a mask. What can be done to make the flights more safe?

At first, I was thinking: maybe these people are right, when there are strict regulations on who can board (vaccination or test) the masks are redundant? But it cannot be true, there are categories of people that do not need tests (children below 12) who can still carry the infection. Also, as we all know tests and vaccinations are not 100% effective.

May second thought was, one should wear a mask even all other measures are 100% effective, just to show solidarity and adherence to the law.

I also think the WiZZ airline, being a low-cost carrier, has no interest in implementing any COVID measures because they increase the cost. Therefore, it is unlikely they would do anything in response to my complaint.

But what can be done then?

Comment: Comments are not for extended discussion; this conversation has been [moved to chat](https://chat.stackexchange.com/rooms/129320/discussion-on-question-by-yarchik-what-can-i-do-when-i-see-passengers-without-ma).

Answer (score 116, accepted):

I work for an airline (cabin crew management). We face a lot of passengers who have issues with masks, but we aggressively enforce it. We simply remove those who decline to wear the masks from the flight. If a passenger removes it during the flight and declines to put it on again, airport security will be waiting for him/her after landing.

**What can be done if the airline does not enforce this while the law requires it?**

Reputation! go online (it seems you've already done this) and post some photos (if this is allowed where you live), report them to the civil aviation authorities, airport authorities or health authorities (they love to collect fines, airlines hate to pay them), leave comments at the airline rating websites (such as [airlinequality.com](https://www.airlinequality.com/)).

Low cost carriers do not have much to offer beside the low prices and the promise of taking you safely from A to B, they cannot afford to lose that. And remember, although the authorities take time to respond, but they usually do. Most likely they will not respond back to you, but for sure they will contact the airline.

Comment: Comments are not for extended discussion; this conversation has been [moved to chat](https://chat.stackexchange.com/rooms/129340/discussion-on-answer-by-nean-der-thal-what-can-i-do-when-i-see-passengers-withou).